# $G$ is doubly transitive on a set $S$ if and only if $G=HTH$ where $H$ is an isotropy subgroup and $T$ is a group of order 2 not contained in $H$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

This is Exercise 47(b) from Chapter 1 of Lang's Algebra.  In part $(a)$ one is asked to show that $G$ is doubly transitive if and only if $H$ is transitive on $S\setminus\{s\}$.  I've been able to prove that part.  As for the title in the question, I've been able to prove a partial result.  Namely,
$$G=H\cup HgH$$
where $g\notin H$.

I've looked a few references but I can find the result of the exercise.  Decomposing $G$ into the double cosets is the best result I can find.

Comment: What is your question exactly? Also "$T$ is a subgroup of order $2$ contained in $S$" does not make sense because $S$ is not a group.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I've edited the title.

Comment: My question is how would one prove that $G=HTH$.  The best I can do is show that $G$ is the union of two double cosets.

Comment: $T$ not contained in $G$ does not make sense either! Do you mean $T$ is not a subgroup of $H$?  Are you supposed to prove it for all subgroups of order two that are not contained in $H$ or just for some such subgroup?

Comment: @DerekHolt Ugh.  I'm having one of those day.  Yes, I mean $H$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $t$ be any element of $G \setminus H$. Then, since you have already proved that $G = H \cup HgH$, we must have $t \in HgH$ and hence $HgH=HtH$. Let $T = \langle t \rangle$. Then $1 \in T$ and so $H = H1H \le HTH$, and also $HgH = HtH \le HTH$, so $G=HTH$.

This applies in particular when $t$ and $T$ have order $2$. The fact that $G$ is doubly transitive implies that we can conjugate an involution in $G$ to an involution that is not contained in $H$, so such elements $t$ of order $2$ exist.

Comment: One question, how do we know that $G$ has an involution to begin with?

Comment: A group acting doubly transitively on a set $S$ with $|S|=n$ has order $n(n-1)k$, where $k$ is the order of a stabilizer of two points. So it must have even order and hence contain an element of order $2$.