# How do i prove that $G$ doubly transitive if and only if $G=HTH$ where $H$ is isotropy subgroup and $|T|=2$?

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

For personal interest, I'm working on an solution of Serge Lang's Algebra.

Then I came across a problem about a doubly transitive group, exercise 47(b) of Chapter 1. I know there's [already a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1621200/g-is-doubly-transitive-on-a-set-s-if-and-only-if-g-hth-where-h-is-an-iso) on this site about the same issue, but I couldn't find the answer in that question, so I'm here to ask.

Question is below, and I have no idea to deal with. I've tried for some $G\ni t:(a,s)\mapsto(s,a)$ where $H$ is isotropy subgroup of $s$, but I cannot prove that $t$ is order 2.

Any help would be greatly welcomed.

> $G$ acts transitively and faithfully over a set $S$ which has more than one element and $H$ is isotropy subgroup of $s\in S$. Prove that $G$ is doubly transitive if and only if $G=HTH$, where $|T|=2$, $T<G$.

I already know that $G$ acts doubly transitive if and only if $\forall s\in S$, $G_s$ acts transitively on $S\setminus\{s\}$.

Comment: *Hint*. The double cosets $\{HtH\}$ are the $H$-orbits of $H$ acting on $G/H$ by left multiplication.

Comment: @coiso Oh I forgot that. I edited it just now...